# Двукратное присвоение свойства переменной - зачем?

Tags: javascript

Нашёл такой вот интересный *Cross-File Private State* паттерн (кому интересно,
[ссылочка](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html)).

```js
var MODULE = (function(my) {
  var _private = my._private = my._private || {},
    _seal = my._seal = my._seal || function() {
      delete my._private;
      delete my._seal;
      delete my._unseal;
    },
    _unseal = my._unseal = my._unseal || function() {
      my._private = _private;
      my._seal = _seal;
      my._unseal = _unseal;
    };

  // permanent access to _private, _seal, and _unseal

  return my;
}(MODULE || {}));
```

Интересует в нём следующий момент:

```
var _private = my._private = my._private || {}
```

**Вопрос**: Зачем два раза повторять присваивание одно и того же свойства?
Почему нельзя было просто написать `var _private = my._private || {}`?

Answer (score 7):

Затем, что если свойство `my._private` все-таки было неинициализировано, то после "двойного" присваивания

```
var _private = my._private = my._private || {}
```

оно станет объектом `{}` - тем же объектом, на который будет ссылаться локальная переменная `_private`.

Аналогично - для `my._seal` и `my._unseal`.

Comment: Хорошо, но это происходит после второго знака равно. После первого же - лишь присвоение, без проверки на существование данного свойства у объекта. Так почему бы сразу не написать вот так:
var _private = my._private || {} ?

Comment: @ПавелЛозовиков Оператор присвоения в javascript-е возвращает присвоеное значение. Это раз. Цепочка присвоений выполняется справа налево. Это два.